# ruby json new line break rendered format incorrectly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api, line-breaks

i tried to `rendor json format` in ruby on rails

**My code:(`ruby code`)**

```
:address=> 'Address:\nshollinganallur,\nchennai.'
```

**Rendered json output:**

```
"address": "Address:\\nshollinganallur,\\nchennai."
```

I tried with old questions and answer. but nothing happend. Any help?

Comment: What old questions did you look at?

Comment: Good. In the future, linking to things that seem relevant helps people help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no newlines in this:

```
:address=> 'Address:\nshollinganallur,\nchennai.'
```

The `\n` escape sequence doesn't work in single quoted strings so you're just getting the two characters `\` and `n`.

When that's converted to JSON, the `\` has a meaning so it has to be escaped with another `\`. Hence the output you're seeing.

If you start with:

```
:address => "Address:\nshollinganallur,\nchennai."
```

then you'll get your newlines all the way through.